# Jersey Client: Sending trailers in HTTP request with chunked transfer

Tags: java, chunked-encoding, jersey-client

I am implementing a java client to upload large files to the Akamai NetStorage Version 4 (Object Storage) via HTTP API. When using chunked transfer, the API requires trailing headers (trailers) to be send at the end of the message body.

Currently I use Jersey 1.x with ApacheHttpClient. I could not find any methods to set these trailers for the request.

I found an example how they can be added in a ChunkedOutputStream here (they are named "footers"):
https://github.com/andyburke/bitflood/blob/master/clients/java/src/ChunkedOutputStream.java
But I would have to hack the whole Jersey Client implementation to support this.

So I am looking for a smart solution... any ideas?